# How to get PHP 7.1 to use libreadline.so.8?

Tags: php, manjaro, readline

After an update of my Manjaro system, my PHP server stopped working, with the error "php: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

It was probably caused by te fact that Readline was updated to version 8 and the old version deleted.

So is it possible to tell PHP 7.1 (php71-noconflict, 7.1.26) to use readline 8, or to somehow get both versions working?

Comment: I have successfully downgraded the library and started php server, but then bash started complaining. So I will need a way to either get php 7.1 working with readline8 or get both versions working along.

Comment: Okay, seems like I broke my system completely now. As Bash is missing the readline8 library, I cannot do almost anything. I cannot install readline8 neither using package manager, nor using their own install script. What can I do now? Is there any solution?

Comment: Why didn't you just make a symlink of `libreadline.so.7` pointing to `libreadline.so.8` or compile `readline-7.0` from source and then put the library path in a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and then run `ldconfig`?

Comment: Okay, I did so, thank you. As I am not a very experienced user, it took me a lot of time, and at first I believed that PHP would not work with the new major version, so at first I tried to compile and use the old version, but that gave me errors all the time. The symlinked new version works.

Comment: I'll post the symlink solution as an answer.

Comment: Great, I will mark it as accepted, thank you once again!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a symlink in `/usr/lib`:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7
```